# Loop JPA array without triggering Lob fetch

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

If have defined the following Spring JPA Entities:

```
@Entity
class Album(
        @Id
        val id: Long = 0,
        ...
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "album")
        val mediaItems: Set<Media>) : Serializable

@Entity
@Table(name = "media")
class Media(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
        var id: Long? = null,
        @Column
        @Lob
        var content: ByteArray
```

The definition includes a lazy fetched @Lob column, which actually is lazy since the underlaying database use Postgres large objects. My spring jpa is backed by hibernate. When looping through the mediaItems spring jpa entries all entries automatically fetch their associated @Lob content without even touching the content column. This Lob output is not needed for the current serialization and slows down the loop tremendously. Here is my loop:

```
val albumProtocs = MediaProtocs.AlbumList.newBuilder().addAllAlbum(
                ownAlbum.map { album ->

                    MediaProtocs.Album.newBuilder()
                            .setId(album.id)
                            .setName(album.name)
                            .addAllMedia(album.mediaItems.map { media ->
                                MediaProtocs.Media.newBuilder().setId(media.id as Long)
                                        .setDescription(media.description)
                                        .setMimeType(media.mimetype).build()
                            }).build()
                }).build()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate load all lazy fields, if you call any method of entity object, except getters. You just need to find which method is called.

You can try to load the list of media directly without the album. Also you can try to load a list of media to list of DTO using projections.

Comment: I tried your advice out and it turned out as expected. Hibernate gets triggered by just looping over my media set. The following will trigger the behavior:  for (media in ownAlbum.mediaItems) {}. I suspected this might be a bug by combining Kotlin and Hibernate.

Comment: I dug even deeper it's the call to this List.size() which triggers the behavior.

Comment: @Jacob Hibernate should load all the collection `mediaItems` with List.size(). Without lazy fields of elements, of course. Maybe you have eager loading of `Lob`. What happens if you get one `Media` by id? I updated my answer.

Comment: In my case also the lazy elements loaded. I tried the following ways: a while loop, manual fetching of the media list, spring jpa Java 8 Streams. All had the same result. I went for using projections which worked fine. Thanks!